# Internationalization in a WebPart?

Tags: sharepoint, internationalization, web-parts, multilingual

I made a WebPart for a Sharepoint 2010, but it must be available in more than one language.

What is the best way to create a Multilingual WebPart?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://geekswithblogs.net/venkatx5/archive/2010/12/14/how-to-create-multilingual-webpart-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the ASP.NET Resources, they are made for these kind of functionality. An MSDN link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163566.aspx

Of course the [link of Tom Vervoort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419268/internationalization-in-a-webpart/5430939#5430939) is great for the actual implementation of the resources.